# Option to set "authorized redirect URL" missing under API and Services > Credentials > Edit

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have been working on a google cloud project for the past few months. it involves working with Google Drive APIs. Initially I had created credentials for a Desktop App and at that moment it did allow me to specify a redirect URL but now when I click on "Edit" for that same desktop app credential, the option to specify the "Authorized Redirect URL" is missing.

[google cloud console credentials page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdDXE.png)

[desktop app credentials edit options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXSj3.png)

[web app credentials edit option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEweN.png)

Creating a new desktop app credential did not help as the option to setup redirect URL was missing there as well.I created a Web App credentials and those give me the option to setup a redirect URL just fine. The problem that I noticed with using the web app credentials is that the refresh token is not generated even when you specify response_type=code in the login URL for your application.

[Postman showing access token generation using web app client id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r6AU.png)

On Google Support page: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#request-parameter-redirect_uri. it says the following:

"Loopback IP address (macOS, Linux, Windows desktop)
Important: The loopback IP address redirect option is DEPRECATED for the Android, Chrome app, and iOS OAuth client types. Review the loopback IP address migration guide for instructions on how to migrate to a supported alternative.

To receive the authorization code using this URL, your application must be listening on the local web server. That is possible on many, but not all, platforms. However, if your platform supports it, this is the recommended mechanism for obtaining the authorization code."

it says that its deprecated for Android, Chrome app, and iOS OAuth client types but I am using a desktop app client id for a windows desktop application. Does it still mean that I am stuck with "localhost:80" ? Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop application dont need a redirect URI its automatically http :\ 127.0.0.1 and you can't change that if you check the json file you downloaded its in there

## web app

a refresh token will only be created if you request offline access.

Comment: I understand that now. Thank you for providing clarification on the same.